# VB.Net - MSBuild Configuration - Selectively Include Files To Build With

Tags: .net, msbuild

I'm looking for a way to selectively include a set of third-party DLL's to build with based on the configuration specified. The references for Version1 and Version2 do not need to change, just the DLL's that are included in the build.

To be more specific, both Version1 and Version2 include the same DLLs, just different versions. So they both for example have the libraries:

- Library.Common.dll
- Library.Orange.dll
- Library.Red.dll

My code then references interfaces/classes/commands defined within those DLLs. I want to be able to easily switch between using Version1's version of those DLLs as content and using Version2's version of those DLLs as content.

Ideally, I'd be able to do something like:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release_Version1|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>bin\Release_Version1\</OutputPath>
    <!-- Looking for the correct way to do the line below -->
    <IncludeItemGroup name="Version1"/>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release_Version2|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>bin\Release_Version2\</OutputPath>
    <!-- Looking for the correct way to do the line below -->
    <IncludeItemGroup name="Version2"/>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup Label="Version1">
    <Content Include="lib\Version1\*.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Label="Version2">
    <Content Include="lib\Version2\*.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Does anyone have a good suggestion for this?

Comment: "Included in the build" is very vague.  You are showing just file(s) that are marked as `<Content>`.  Nothing special happens to them, they are not included in the build.  Only an installer cares about content.  What is supposed to happen with them?

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I have modified a bit to expand on what I mean, but I am most likely approaching the situation incorrectly. Currently, I have two Project folder, one for the DLLs in Version1 and one for the DLLs in Version2. I then Include\Exclude these Project folders depending on which version of the DLLs I want to build against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, it looks like you would want to add a condition to each `ItemGroup` element, related to the value of `$(Configuration)`.

```
<ItemGroup Label="Version1" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release_Version1' ">
    <Content Include="lib\Version1\*.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Label="Version2" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release_Version2' ">
    <Content Include="lib\Version2\*.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```